# How can I better represent a cross-cutting component in an ERD

Tags: design-principles, data-visualisation, information-design

I am creating an ERD for a training roadmap as shown below. The *soft skills* component is cross-cutting in all levels. Is that the best way to represent it?

[image: training ERD]